# What is the difference between inherits and implements in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public class HitController : MonoBehaviour, ICentroidHitListener
```

The way I understand it. HitController inherits from MonoBehaviour and implements the methods in the ICentroidHitListener.

But how can I code this if I just want it only to implement the methods in the ICentroidListener? Do I code it like this:

```
public class HitController : ICentroidHitListener
```

In which case that looks like HitController inherits from ICentroidHitListener

Comment: Good question, one most people would probably be afraid to ask, myself included.

Comment: If you switch to VB.NET, you get the beautiful and unambiguous `Inherits` and `Implements` keywords ;)

Comment: the convention `I` for Interface differentiates an Interface from class.Thats it...There's no way to avoid it!

Comment: @minitech: You forgot to mention the baggage that comes with that - i.e. the ugly language that is way too verbose in many other cases. :p

Comment: This is only confusing when you write a **class**. The class will always inherit exactly one base class. If you choose not to specify which one, it will be `object` (also known as `System.Object`). But you **could** choose to write `public class HitController : object, ICentroidHitListener` if you want to make sure it's obvious what's the base class, and what's the interface list. A class can implement zero, one, two or more interfaces.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If it's an interface, `:` implements the interface. If it's a class, `:` inherits from the class.

Therefore `HitController : ICentroidHitListener` is correct.

Comment: And if it's a numerical type keyword like `int`, `byte`, `ulong` or many others, then that's the underlying type of the enum being declared.

Comment: Almost entirely true. Abstract classes get implemented too.

Comment: @Tom: I might be wrong, but I’d still say they get inherited. They can contain implementation.

Comment: @Ryan now that you say that.. Well yeah, Can't disagree. But then classes with abstract methods.. What about those?

Answer (score 13):

Generally, there is no way to differentiate an interface from a class using the `:` syntax.

That's why it's important to add an `I` prefix to all your interfaces.

The code you provided, `public class HitController : ICentroidHitListener`, is correct, and the readers of your code should be able to easily and quickly deduce that it is an interface based on the `I` prefix.

Taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx):

> When a class or struct implements an interface, the class or struct
>   provides an implementation for all of the members defined by the
>   interface. The interface itself provides no functionality that a class
>   or struct can inherit in the way that base class functionality can be
>   inherited. However, if a base class implements an interface, the
>   derived class inherits that implementation. The derived class is said
>   to implement the interface implicitly.

Taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx):

> Inheritance enables you to create new classes that reuse, extend, and
>   modify the behavior that is defined in other classes. The class whose
>   members are inherited is called the base class, and the class that
>   inherits those members is called the derived class. A derived class
>   can have only one direct base class. However, inheritance is
>   transitive. If ClassC is derived from ClassB, and ClassB is derived
>   from ClassA, ClassC inherits the members declared in ClassB and
>   ClassA.

In C#, as opposed to languages like C++, [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) is not allowed, meaning that a class cannot inherit from more than one other class. Conversely, a class *can* implement more than one interface.

Answer (score 6):

"inheritance" implies extending existing behaviour.  An interface has no behaviour, you have to implement all the behaviour of the methods/properties defined in the interface.  Hence you "implement" an interface and cannot really inherit anything from it.

If you inherit from something else, you inherit all its concrete behaviour.  If some other class implements an interface you don't have to also implement that interface.  Now, the class that "implements" that interface could make one or more of those interface implementations "abstract"; in which case you'd be forced to implement the abstract members of the class you're deriving from.  But, you don't have to implement that interface--you inherit the interface from the base.  You can include the interface in the "base class list" for the derived type, but it's not necessary.

By that token, you'd also "implement" an entirely abstract class.  But, it's rare that anyone would use that terminology.  For the most part "interface" is syntax sugar in .NET; but it does have IL-level support.  e.g. an entirely abstract base class is semantically identical to an interface.

Interfaces let you ensure the only thing you can do is define an interface and not behaviour (an abstract class can have behaviour).

Comment: +1. One main difference between abstract classes and interfaces is that a class can inherit from exactly one base class, but can implement many interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to what you're asking is "yes", if I understand it correctly.

In the first example, you are *inheriting* from a base class (`MonoBehavior`) and *implementing* an interface (`ICentroidHitLIstener`').

You have access to all the members of `MonoBehavior` from your `HitController` class, and your `HitController` class must provide implementation for all members defined in the `ICentroidHitListener` interface.

In the second example, you are only implementing the `ICentroidHitListener` interface.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy.
Inheriting is gaining base class features to yours.
Implementing is creating features according to specified protocol.

class:class and interface:interface is inheritance, 
class:interface is implementing, 
class:abstract_class are both implementing and inheritance.