# Cannot call method from another class without static field

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I have interface with this code

```
interface IHttpRequest
{
    Task<string> GetCountries();
}
```

That I inherit in class like this

```
public class GettingCountries: IHttpRequest
{
    public async Task<string> GetCountries()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://api.xplorpal.com");
        var request = new RestRequest("/countries", Method.POST);
        var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
        var content = response.Content;
        var responseCountries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<GettingCountry.RootObjectCountries>>(content);

        GettingCountry.CountriesList.Clear();
        GettingCountry.ListOfCountriesRoot.Clear();

        foreach (var country in responseCountries)
        {
            GettingCountry.CountriesList.Add(country.nicename);
            GettingCountry.ListOfCountriesRoot.Add(new GettingCountry.RootObjectCountries(country.id, country.nicename));
        }
        return content;
    }


}
```

After this I need to call method of this class somewhere, like this for example `var countries_list = await GettingCountries.GetCountries();`

But now I have error.

[image]

How I can solve it? I can make it static, but is this ok? Maybe smth other?

Comment: You can create instance object for `GettingCountries` instead of making it static.

Comment: `await (new GettingCountries()).GetCountries();`? But presumably there's a reason that this is being defined on an interface, so there may be a "better" way of obtaining the "correct" instance rather than `new`ing one up.

Comment: seems thats it. Thank's @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: You need to create an instance of `GettingCountries` before calling its methods. (+I'm picky but you don't inherit from an interface, you implement it)

Comment: Yeah. But, I'm inherit interface, and that implement it@vc74

Comment: Not sure I'm following you. `GettingCountries` implements `IHttpRequest`, it does not inherit from `IHttpRequest`. In other words `IHttpRequest` is an interface, not a parent class.

Comment: @EugeneSukh implementing an interface is very different than inheriting a base class. Read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843692/inheritance-internal-class-vs-internal-interface/52944818#52944818) to [Inheritance: Internal Class vs. Internal Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843692/inheritance-internal-class-vs-internal-interface) and also [What is the difference between inherits and implements in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020286/what-is-the-difference-between-inherits-and-implements-in-c-sharp) for more details.